# Enforce constraint regarding other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table with bid to an auction and **every licitation bid to some auction should be higher than every other regarding that same auction**.
How can this be done? As I don't know a way to make a constraint work I thought about using a trigger but didn't find any with a similar objective (I'm really new to sql).

My table creation SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE bid(
  id_auction NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  username  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  amount    FLOAT   NOT NULL,
  b_date DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_bid PRIMARY KEY (id_auction, username, amount),
  FOREING KEY (username) REFERENCES user(username),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_auction) REFERENCES auction(id_auction)
```

);

My incomplete trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER high_bid_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON bid
DECLARE
    highest_bid NUMBER;
BEGIN
    highest_bid := (SELECT min(amount)
                    FROM bid
                    WHERE username = :NEW.username
                    AND id_aution = :NEW.id_auction)
    if highest_bid < :NEW:bid
```

I'm using an Oracle database.

Comment: First, probably change min for max and get rid of "WHERE username" as per your bolded requirements. Second, you will likely need to use RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. Once you've done those 2 things, please include the message that the interpreter gives when you try to create the trigger and when you test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a trigger, I think.  When you get data from the same table in a trigger, you can have a problem with mutating triggers.  These are hard to fix.

I don't know if it is feasible, but you could solve this problem by storing the *increment* rather than the absolute value.  Then, you can guarantee that the increment is greater than 0:

```
constraint chk_t_increment check (increment > 0);
```

This is messy when you want to query the values, however.

Another option would be to use an *after insert* trigger to maintain the data in another table.  So, the auction table would have a column for the current highest bid.

You can then use this value in a *before insert* trigger, where the old value would be used.

This type of problem is an example of why I like to wrap data modification steps into stored procedures, rather than handling them through direct calls to `update`/`insert`/`delete`.  A stored procedure would give the flexibility to do what you want to do rather easily with no triggers involved.

Comment: I add one additional note to your answer : Solution with any trigger incompatible when several sessions insert data simultaneously.

Comment: The first option is not possible because the increment is not for the collumn but for the collumn regarding each auction_id. Why would a solution with a trigger be incompatible with multiple sessions?

Comment: About that second ideia of storing the highest bid in the auction table: If it wasn't how do I set an error and stop the insertion?

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer Trigger body can be call simultaneously while two parallel insert and they will not see changes in other sessions till commit. More over this kind of trigger is issue of statement restart. It occurs very seldom but can be issue of some weird behaviour.(especially when exists complicated predicats in where clause)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the application and not for the database.

Answer (score 0):

As Dudu said, this is best done at the application level.

If for some reason you must do this in the database, your best bet is probably a materialized view with fast refresh on commit. The view could contain, for example, a count of all bid amounts strictly greater than the most recent bid amount, grouped by id, from the base table. On this materialized view you can have a constraint that all the values must be zero.

Whenever an "offending" insert is attempted, a value of 1 would be attempted to be inserted in the materialized view. That will be rejected. That's your constraint!

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:4233459000346171405

Answer (score 0):

I would make a procedure to do this:

```
-- Create Bid Table
CREATE TABLE bid
(
    bid_id       INTEGER
  , bid_amount   DECIMAL (6, 2)
  , bidder       VARCHAR2 (30)
);

-- Use this procedure to make a bid
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE make_bid (
    p_bid_id       IN bid.bid_id%TYPE
  , p_bid_amount   IN bid.bid_amount%TYPE
  , p_bidder       IN bid.bidder%TYPE
)
AS
    -- **********************************************************************
    --  Make Bid
    --  Purpose:
    --    Make a bid on an auction item
    --  Arguments:
    --    p_bid_id     - id of item being bid upon
    --    p_bid_amount - amount of the bid
    --    p_bidder     - account of the bidder
    --  Notes:
    --    Throws an exception if bid amount does not exceed previous bid
    -- **********************************************************************
    l_max_previous_bid   bid.bid_amount%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Coalesce is used to set previous bid to 0 if no bids have been made.
    SELECT COALESCE (MAX (bid_amount), 0.0)
      INTO l_max_previous_bid
      FROM bid
     WHERE bid_id = p_bid_id;

    -- Throw an exception if bid does not exceed previous bid (or zero)
    IF p_bid_amount <= l_max_previous_bid
    THEN
        raise_application_error (
            -20001
          ,    'Bid amount <= TO current bid amount'
            || UTL_TCP.crlf
            || RPAD ('BID_ID', 20)
            || ': '
            || l_max_previous_bid
            || UTL_TCP.crlf
            || RPAD ('Bid Amount', 20)
            || ': '
            || p_bid_amount
            || UTL_TCP.crlf
            || RPAD ('Exisiting Bid Amount', 20)
            || ': '
            || l_max_previous_bid
            || UTL_TCP.crlf
            || RPAD ('Bidder', 20)
            || ': '
            || p_bidder
        );
    END IF;

    -- if we got to here, everything is good
    -- Update the record to the new bid
    UPDATE bid
       SET bidder = p_bidder, bid_amount = p_bid_amount
     WHERE bid.bid_id = p_bid_id;

      -- if zero rows were updated, there is no existing bid on the object
      -- and we need to add a new value.
    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
    THEN
        INSERT INTO brianl.bid (
                   bid_id, bid_amount, bidder
                    )
             VALUES (p_bid_id, p_bid_amount, p_bidder);
    END IF;
END make_bid;
```